# Custom Pandas Dataframe to HTML

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe i want to group, separate and export to htlm for a specific presentation.  I have performed the to_htlm() method but does not produce the output I looking for.

My sample data look like this:

| id | color | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Red | 20 |
| 1 | Red | 25 |
| 1 | Blue | 20 |
| 1 | Blue | 15 |
| 1 | Green | 5 |
| 2 | Red | 100 |
| 2 | Blue | 20 |
| 2 | Blue | 220 |
| 2 | Blue | 120 |
| 2 | Blue | 20 |
| 2 | Green | 220 |
| 2 | Green | 120 |
| 2 | Green | 45 |
| 2 | Green | 2 |
| 2 | Green | 5 |

My desired htlm output is a grouping by ID, then Color

Id: 1

| color | value |
| --- | --- |
| Red | 20 |
| Red | 25 |

| color | value |
| --- | --- |
| Blue | 20 |
| Blue | 15 |

| color | value |
| --- | --- |
| Green | 5 |

Id: 2

| color | value |
| --- | --- |
| Red | 100 |

| color | value |
| --- | --- |
| Blue | 20 |
| Blue | 220 |
| Blue | 120 |
| Blue | 20 |

| color | value |
| --- | --- |
| Green | 220 |
| Green | 120 |
| Green | 45 |
| Green | 2 |
| Green | 5 |

Is there an efficent way to dynamically generate the htlm by looping through the main dataframe and grouping the data as desired?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try this :

```
grp = df.groupby(["id", "color"], sort=False)

tables, last_id = {}, None

for name, g in grp:
    id_ = name[0]
    
    if last_id != id_:
        title = f"<p>Id: {id_}</p>\n"
        tables[name] = title
    else:
        title = ""
    
    thtml = g.drop(columns="id").to_html(index=False)
    tables[name] = f"{title}{thtml}<br>\n"
    
    last_id = id_
    
with open("output.html", "w") as f:
    f.write("".join(tables.values()))
```

Ouptut ([*HTML demo*](https://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/y23a95e56)) :

[image]